# Cache images in custom adapters

Tags: android, caching, android-adapter

I'm a little bit confused about the caching procedure when the images are stored into a custom ArrayAdapter....

As far as I know you can use LruCache only on Activities, so how to cache images in an adapter?

Comment: What images? Are you talking about images you download?

Comment: In this particular case there are local images (Drawables), but my question is more general, Android docs don't explain it so clearly

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean - you want to cache the drawables? Can you post your code?

Comment: It's just a demo app....I got a listFragment and each row has an ImageView; these ImageViews have a drawable as src; I simply want to cache them to avoid glitches on low memory devices (I already resized these images)

Answer (score 1):

A *Cache* is just a data structure that keeps track of Objects. You can create your own cache, then save, for example, bitmaps using URLs as keys. For example, take this Object:

```
public static Map<String, Object> cache = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

This is your cache. You can now save images by their urls. For example, say you get a bitmap from *http://www.example.com/img.png*. A simple method like this will get the cached image if it exists, or get a new one if it does not:

```
public Bitmap getImage(String url)
{
    synchronized(cache) {
        Object o = cache.get(url);
        if (o != null)
            return (Bitmap) o;
        //here, get the bitmap from the URL using whatever method you want, then save it and return it:
        Bitmap bmp = getBitmapForURL(url);
        cache.put(url, bmp);
        return bmp;
    }
}
```

So you just call:

```
myImageView.setImageBitmap(getImage("http://www.example.com/img.png"));
```

Comment: is this not possible using LruCache?

Comment: @tizionario yes, this looks like I rewrote `LruCache`. Also note that both implementations **are not restricted to Activities**.

Comment: really? Reading from Android doc, it seems that I can use LruCache only on Activities, didn't know that

Answer (score 0):

Store only image URIs in adapter not the images.

Comment: even with local drawables?

Comment: so you're saying to store images into the adapter with their uri, then caching them on the activity, right?